# Método de extención en c# Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

alguien me puede ayudar acerca de como debo crear un método de extensión para el evento keyPress, verán mi problemática es la siguiente he desarrollado un código que me permite realizar un salto de control dentro de un formulario ya sea mediante presionar la tecla enter o espacio este codigo funciona bien lo que pasa es que tengo mas de 10 formularios diferentes entonces lo que he realizado de momento es copiar y pegarlo en cada formulario pero siempre es el mismo código y pues. al parecer tendré que desarrollar mas formularios debido a esto estoy buscado de introducir este código en una sola clase para solo hacer un instancia del método cuando lo necesite pero de momento no lo he logrado. Si me pudieran orientar con algún ejemplo similar estaría súper.

```
public void Enter_KeyPressClick(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e){
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)(Keys.Enter))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            }

            if (e.KeyChar == (char)(Keys.Space))
            {
                DevExpress.XtraEditors.ButtonEdit BotonActual = (DevExpress.XtraEditors.ButtonEdit)sender;
                BotonActual.PerformClick(BotonActual.Properties.Buttons[0]);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Genera una nueva clase en el espacio de nombres donde tienes las ventanas, por ejemplo:

```
namespace MiPrograma.Windows
{
    // La clase donde coloques tus métodos de extensión debe ser estática
    internal static class ExtensionWindowEvent
    {
        /* Los métodos deben:
         * 1. Ser estáticos (static)
         * 2. Incluir como primer parámetro un objeto de la clase que va a
         *    implementar la extensión, en este caso "Form" y debe ser marcado
         *    como "this".
         */
        public static void Common_KeyPressClick(this Form form, object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)(Keys.Enter))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            }

            if (e.KeyChar == (char)(Keys.Space))
            {
                DevExpress.XtraEditors.ButtonEdit BotonActual = (DevExpress.XtraEditors.ButtonEdit)sender;
                BotonActual.PerformClick(BotonActual.Properties.Buttons[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y en tus formularios puedes llamarlo simplemente así:

```
public void Enter_KeyPressClick(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) => this.Common_KeyPressClick(sender, e);
```

Da lo mismo si usas la notación de flecha `=>` o si prefieres usarlo como cuerpo de la función:

```
public void Enter_KeyPressClick(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    this.Common_KeyPressClick(sender, e);
}
```